# How do you send code review requests with git when devs do not have public work repositories?

Tags: git

Normally in Git, each developer will clone from the origin into a personal tracking repo, make some changes, then send a fetch request to the manager referencing his personal machine which has a git-daemon, or web server, or allows the manager to connect to it with ssh.

For some changes its alright for the dev to check in stuff himself. For larger ones, other people like to look at it before it gets checked into master. So the dev does have the privilege to check into the repository.

But what if the manager couldn't connect to other devs work machines, and only had access to the origin git repo, or email? What is the best way to send the diffs to him for review?

We could send patches in an email or the dev could push his branch out to origin and tell the manager to `git fetch origin; git diff master..case223`. Or is there another better way?

Comment: The process described is actually similar to Integration Manager Workflow. Check the [progit chapter](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html) and also take a look at [`git --help workflows`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html)

Answer (score 7):

I would use

```
git format-patch <branch-to-compare-against> --cover-letter -o patches/
```

which will essentially create the appropriate patches for your commits
and then

```
git send-email --to <receiver@example.com> --annotate patches/*
```

Check the man pages:

- [format-patch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html)
- [send-email](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-send-email.html) and the example section

Comment: I received an error when running send-email on OSX. Any idea why?

'the editor exited uncleanly, aborting everything at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-send-email line 213.'

Answer (score 3):

Git bundle

```
git bundle create myproposal.git origin/sharedbranch..HEAD
```

You can receive it as if it were a repo:

```
cd myworktree
git pull /tmp/myproposal.git
```

Incidentally, git bundle is also the most effective way to backup your entire repo, e.g.

```
git bundle create /tmp/backup.git --all --tags --remotes
```

Comment: Cool, Ive never heard of this command before. I think I would prefer to use this then fill a directory full of patches if I was sending emails or linking to the shared directories.

Comment: Me too; also note that the compression is awesome; select a proper base revision (`sharedbranch` in the example) and you'll sending kilobytes at most for most useful scenarios

Comment: `git bundle` is nice if you have the ability to have the repo locally and be able to apply the bundle to your branch. 

`git format-patch` and `git send-email` are more appropriate for reviews as you actually see the patches, not going throught the apply-the-bundle process. Especially if you've set up a mailing list for the project where devs and managers can comment before accepting the patches.

Comment: I personally never accept a patch on just _viewing_ it on a list. Ever.

Comment: @sehe I understand that :) That's why [`git-am`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) is there. If the patch is approved then `git-am` is used to generate the patch from the e-mail. The gitpro book has a small [chapter](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_and_email.html) describing that.

Comment: As I said `git bundle` is nice and I hold nothing against it, but with `git send-email` you can see the patch, without having to create it. If there are obvious faults why do the hassle, if people have better opions on improving some part why not quote and suggest an alternative ? you can even reply to that thread through `git send-email` with a fix-patch. I guess it boils down to how the team works and what the desired workflow is.

Answer (score 2):

Allow the devs to push to certain branches on the same repo. Use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) to administer who has what kind of access to what branch. No need to email stuff back and forth.

UPDATE: since then, I've written this article: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've done something like this. What steps would you suggest with this approach? Perhaps the dev pushes to a new branch just for his review(s), then the reviewer(s) pull/check out the branch, and either manually checks the commit(s) that the dev made using their usual diff tools, or could use the diff commands that compare two branches.

Comment: since this post, I've written out the work flow here: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Comment: now all we do is do a `git diff master..feature123` or `git log -p master..feature123` if we want to ensure TDD and want to see each commit. `tig` is also good for this.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless advertisement: I suggest you also to consider [Gerrit](http://gerrit.googlecode.com).

We use it for our code reviews, and it's an amazing tool (especially the possibilities for access rights). With that, every developer here can push his changes into the review branches (and only there), and the other developers can review the changes (they are also automatically built and tested by [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and get verified if the tests were successful).

In your case you would have the right for the manager to submit a change into the repository, we enabled it also for the developers and made only a workflow restriction, that two developers have to review a change to submit it.

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? He asked for "Or is there another better way?" and in my eyes my suggestion is a better way.

Comment: Not sure. Thanks, I might check it out.

Comment: it seems we have some active downvoters. Look at the other answers, and you'll see most of them have been voted down anyway. Personally, I don't get it either, but hey: to each his own, this is <strike> democracy</strike>SO

Answer (score 1):

Note: in addition of [`git send-email`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email), you can use the [`git contacts` contrib script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d2b8a390c2519bf25cd73184c7c6e8baec4208a/contrib/contacts/git-contacts), to list potential contacts interested by your email.

With Git 2.14.x/2.15, that script also detects the "`Reported-by`" section.

See [commit 09ac673](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09ac6737887e26dd2b1f078946400c012955f081) (21 Jul 2017) by [Eric Blake (`BlakeEric`)](https://github.com/BlakeEric).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6d2b8a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d2b8a390c2519bf25cd73184c7c6e8baec4208a), 11 Aug 2017)</sup>

> "`git contacts`" (in `contrib/`) now lists the address on the "Reported-by:" trailer to its output, in addition to those on S-o-b: and other trailers, to make it easier to notify (and thank) the original bug reporter.
>
> ### `git-contacts`: also recognise "`Reported-by:`"
>
> It's nice to cc someone that reported a bug, in order to let them know that a fix is being considered, and possibly even get their help in reviewing/testing the patch.

Of course...

- `S-o-b:` means `Signed-off-by:`
- trailers, [formalized in 2014](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9385b5d7065351104c7bfd3d1e53a28207b8b7ed) are the other part of the commit (`Signed-off-by|Reviewed-by|Acked-by|Cc`)